# Apply different CSS to divs withe same classes

Tags: html, css

**Example:**

**TEXT 1 needs to have different CSS**

```
<div class="cta-content-wrapper">
  <div class="activedemand-text-wrapper">
    <p>
     <span>text1</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TEXT 2 needs to have different CSS**

```
<div class="cta-content-wrapper">
  <div class="activedemand-text-wrapper">
    <p>text2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The HTML code can not be edited and the div id above these divs is unique and changes on reload!

Can someone help me out?

I don't only want to add different colors to the text but also some padding and margin.

Comment: show the full HTML structure

Comment: .cta-content-wrapper:nth-child(1) .activedemand-text-wrapper {.....} .cta-content-wrapper:nth-child(2) .activedemand-text-wrapper {.....}

Comment: This code is not enough to give a full answer, but check out `:nth-child()`, `:first-child` and `:last-child`

Comment: Can´t you just run a js script, that adds a class and css to your specific text?

Comment: @WhoMightThisOneBe I don't know that man :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
   .cta-content-wrapper p > span{
        color: black;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }




     .cta-content-wrapper p{
        color: blue;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
```

```html
<div class="cta-content-wrapper">
  <div class="activedemand-text-wrapper">
    <p>
     <span>text1</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="cta-content-wrapper">
  <div class="activedemand-text-wrapper">
    <p>text2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but when I want to add some margin. That won't work :( Both text will go down and up

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 different .css file like:

style.css

```
.cta-content-wrapper p > span{
    color: black;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

style2.css

```
 .cta-content-wrapper p{
    color: blue;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

html

```
<div class="cta-content-wrapper">
 <div class="activedemand-text-wrapper">
  <p>
   <span>text1</span>
  </p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="cta-content-wrapper">
 <div class="activedemand-text-wrapper">
  <p>text2</p>
 </div>
</div>
```